# Cant get path: /{proxy+} to work (serverless-offline)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-offline

Excuse me if im misunderstanding how this *should* work, im fairly new to the serverless world.

I want to avoid having to explicity list all of my routes in my `serverless.yml` file so have used the catch all `{proxy+}`.

When i run `sls offline start` i see one route listed

`ANY | http://localhost:3000/dev/{proxy+}`

However, when i try to access for example `localhost:3000/dev/test-one` i see the following error `Cannot GET /%7Bproxy+%7D` instead of my expected response.

Am i misunderstanding how to use this?

ps - this works when i explicity list my routes in my `yml` file, but would like to avoid this if poss.

`serverless.yml`

```
service: simply-serverless-web

provider:
  name: aws

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-express

functions:
  app:
    handler: app.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors: any
```

`app.js`

```js
const express = require('serverless-express/express')
const handler = require('serverless-express/handler')
const app = express()

app.all('/test-one', require('./test-one'))
app.all('/test-two', require('./test-two'))
app.all('/test-three', require('./test-three'))

exports.handler = handler(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the stage `dev` that your are using in the url. I dont think its correct for `serverless-offline` environments.

It should be (without `dev`)

```
ANY | http://localhost:3000/{proxy+}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: the /dev/ is added automatically by the serverless offline plugin, and it matches the route correctly.